# Problem with vmlinuz.efi Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, iso

I am tying to install Ubuntu 12.04 along with windows on my PC. when i copy wubi in the folder where my iso file is and start it after some time it gave an error cann not install see log file. In the log file the time when it found my iso and was checking in the next line it gave an error cannot find casper/vmlumiz.efi . when checked iso file it contained that file but there was no extension '.efi' so i extracted it and added that extension and then made it an iso file but the new file's md5 sum was wrong. can anybody help i am using nero 10 oem to make iso.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--32bit` command line argument. i.e. run

```
wubi.exe --32bit
```

It's a new bug that is due to the 64bit kernel being renamed (for secure boot) that occurs if you try to install with the 32bit ISO on a computer that is 64bit capable.